# google drive API to store files from website

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-workspace, cloud-storage

I need to store all the documents that users upload in my website on one Drive account.

These documents are on user's computers. They don't have and do not want to have a Google Drive account.

It is not really clear if the "Google Drive API" can achieve that or if I need "Google Cloud Storage API" that is more expensive for only storing files.

Said API has to create a folder for the documents of each user.

In addition to achieve that, do I need a G suite account?

Thanks a million for your help